# What is causing Numba's AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pysig'?

Tags: python, list, type-inference, numba

When I try to run this code:

```
from numba import njit, int64
from numba.types import List

@njit(int64(List(int64, True)))
def f(a):
    a[0] = 0
    return a[0]

@njit(List(int64)())
def g(): return [f([0])]
```

I get the following. Why is this? How do I make it figure out the types correctly?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Temp.py", line 9, in <module>
    @njit(List(int64)())
  File "numba\decorators.py", line 172, in wrapper
    disp.compile(sig)
  File "numba\dispatcher.py", line 350, in compile
    flags=flags, locals=self.locals)
  File "numba\compiler.py", line 644, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "numba\compiler.py", line 361, in compile_extra
    return self.compile_bytecode(bc, func_attr=self.func_attr)
  File "numba\compiler.py", line 370, in compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "numba\compiler.py", line 631, in _compile_bytecode
    return pm.run(self.status)
  File "numba\compiler.py", line 251, in run
    raise patched_exception
numba.errors.TypingError: Caused By:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numba\compiler.py", line 243, in run
    res = stage()
  File "numba\compiler.py", line 458, in stage_nopython_frontend
    self.locals)
  File "numba\compiler.py", line 759, in type_inference_stage
    infer.propagate()
  File "numba\typeinfer.py", line 510, in propagate
    raise errors[0]
TypingError: Internal error at <numba.typeinfer.CallConstraint object at 0x00000000071C82E8>:
--%<-----------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numba\typeinfer.py", line 111, in propagate
    constraint(typeinfer)
  File "numba\typeinfer.py", line 270, in __call__
    self.resolve(typeinfer, typevars, fnty)
  File "numba\typeinfer.py", line 297, in resolve
    sig = context.resolve_function_type(fnty, pos_args, kw_args)
  File "numba\typing\context.py", line 113, in resolve_function_type
    return func.get_call_type(self, args, kws)
  File "numba\types.py", line 334, in get_call_type
    sig.pysig = self.pysig
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pysig'
--%<-----------------------------------------------------------------
File "Temp.py", line 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the decorator signature for `f` from `@njit(int64(List(int64, True)))` to `@njit(int64(List(int64)))` makes things work for me on Numba 0.31.0.

For `f`, `a` is not a reflected list, so it would appear that setting that flag to `True` is causing issues. For Numba 0.31.0 I get a different error message.

In general though, I would allow Numba to do it's own type inference for the inputs and outputs. I'm not sure what version you're using, but in recent versions, there is rarely a reason to define the types in the decorator signature. If you're curious about what the type inferencer is doing, just use `nb.njit` or `nb.jit(nopython=True)`, call the function with your desired inputs, and then examine `f.inspect_types()` (if your jitted function is `f`).

Comment: It turned out the core problem I was seeing was a bug with my version of Numba (but the problem you mentioned is also there). Thanks! (PS, a problem with letting Numba figure out the types is that it delays that until the invocation, which adds an additional delay I don't like, especially when profiling.)